# data type recognition by parsing array of strings in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, type-conversion

Is there a library that would help to recognize data type from a given array of strings e.g.

```
{"1.0", "2.0", "3.0"} ==>  float, double, decimal (I do not care as long it is a real number)

{"1.0", "AB", "A"} ==> string

{1, 2, 3, 4} ==> Int32

{1.0, 2.5, 1, 2, 3} ==> float/double/decimal
```

recognition of a minimal representation for a given type e.g. float instead of double or short instead of int is an advantage but not neccessary.

Some additinonal data type to recognize: DateTime (few formats possible), +/- signs as pre or postfix, decimal point represented as point or comma, etc.

I need to create a functionality somehow similar to Excel import wizard, where on imput I have a csv text file, and the system should propose data types for each column.

Comment: If you will convert those values into their must accurate presentation, you will need to store them and return them to the caller, which will be `object` type array, and than we didn't accomplish anything.

Comment: You could do a sequence of `TryParse` on successively more "general" types (short -> int -> float -> double, say) until you hit one that succeeds, and falling back to string if none of the tries succeeds.

Comment: @OrelEraki, Yes I am aware of this, but I can store the Type and then use it in my code.

Comment: do a search for a period, if there  then we have a float/double if not check to see if it is numeric...if so then we have an integer and if not a string.

Comment: @SebastianWidz this can be done if you convert the array to a List<object> then from there you can determine what datatype each element in the List<T> is I just posted an example of this last week I will tweak my answer to work for all of your examples

Comment: @senshin, Yes, I start to code this way, int => decimal => string etc., but then new requirement like date in various format came in, and I think there will be more (time / timestamps) strings line $100.000,01 etc. I do not want to end up with 100s of if statements. I'm almost sure somebode wrote some clever lib for it :)

Comment: Nah, it's not very common task. I don't think there's a library for this specific kind of job.

Comment: @SebastianWidz take a look at the answer I posted it will give you an excellent starting point in regards to writing your own class /methods to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can do is to cast to every possible type desired starting from the "*smallest*" to the "*largest*". Something like this:

```
void SetColumnType(string inputString)
{
    bool boolValue;
    short shortValue;
    int intValue;
    float floatValue;

    if (bool.TryParse(inputString, out boolValue))
    {
        // set that column type or whatever to int
    }
    else if (short.TryParse(inputString, out shortValue))
    {
        // ... to short
    }
    else if (int.TryParse(inputString, out intValue))
    {
        // ... to int
    }
    else if (float.TryParse(inputString, out floatValue))
    {
        // ... to float
    }

    // ... etc.
}
```

Comment: how is this going to work when you can't convert a `string[] to a string` ..? you should not post code that does not work especially when the OP specifically is asking about `{ }` string arrays

Comment: Then iterate through the string array.

Comment: not a good example perhaps you should edit it and make sure it works

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<object> dataTypeArr = new  List<object> 
{
    1.0, 
    "AB", 
    "A",
    DateTime.Now
};

var typeList2 = new List<object>();
foreach (var item in dataTypeArr)
{
    typeList2.Add(item.GetType());
}
```

if you want to keep the IList as strings then you can write your own code within the foreach loop to check if item.Contains(".") if so convert it to a decimal or double and then add it to the typeList2 List

if you want to work on the string types and then convert if it contains `.` you can do the following

```
IList<object> dataTypeArr = new  List<object> 
{
    "1.0", 
    "AB", 
    "A",
    DateTime.Now
};

var typeList2 = new List<object>();
foreach (var item in dataTypeArr)
{
    var doubleType = item;
    if (item.ToString().Contains("."))
    {
        doubleType = Convert.ToDouble(item);
        typeList2.Add(doubleType.GetType());
    }
    else
    {
        typeList2.Add(item.GetType());
    }
}
```